# Body scroll on React VectorMap devextreme component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devextreme, devextreme-react

I am using a devextreme `VectorMap` Component, i have disabled **zoom** and **panning**

```
zoomingEnabled={false}
panningEnabled={false}
```

My problem is that even if i scroll on my VectorMap i want the body scrolling. I have reproduced my case here in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-custommap-devextreme-forked-nzsdnb?file=/src/index.js)

As you can see if i scroll on the VectorMap the body is not scrolling, this is not happening if i do the same in the red section below.

How can i achieve the same behaviour?

```
  <VectorMap
    id="vector-map"
    title="Generic Map"
    zoomingEnabled={false}
    panningEnabled={false}
    onClick={(e) => console.log(e)}
  >
    <Layer
      dataSource={pangaeaContinents}
      name="areas"
      color="#bb7862"
    />
  </VectorMap>
```

[Demo Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-custommap-devextreme-forked-nzsdnb?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Devextreme [`VectorMap` Component](https://js.devexpress.com/DevExtreme/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxVectorMap/) has a prop to disable scrolling:

> ##### `wheelEnabled`
>
> Specifies whether or not the map should respond when a user rolls the mouse wheel.
>
> > Type: Boolean
> > Default Value: `true`
>
> Rolling the mouse wheel zooms a map. If you need to disable this capability, assign `false` to the `wheelEnabled` property.
> A user will still be able to zoom the map using the control bar.
>
> #### <sup>[Documentation page](https://js.devexpress.com/DevExtreme/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxVectorMap/Configuration/#wheelEnabled)</sup>

---

```
<VectorMap
    id="vector-map"
    title="Generic Map"
    zoomingEnabled={false}
    panningEnabled={false}
    wheelEnabled={false}
    onClick={(e) => console.log(e)}
>
```

---

Updated snippet:

[image: Edit react-custommap-devextreme (forked)]